# Cant import ydata_profiling import into my google colab environment

Tags: python

I cant import ydata_profiling into my python environment. I do understand that pandas_profiling has been deprecated. Is there anything wrong with my code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to `pip install ydata-profiling`

In any case, they are pretty fast on answering questions in their [Discord](https://discord.gg/mw7xjJ7b7s) server.

Comment: No, am using google colab and no need to install

Comment: Even in Google Colab you need to install it

Comment: The first part of this looks like an answer, but it is phrased as a question. Please rewrite it so folks don't think you're asking a question. (Only answers should be posted as answers.)